# Tesseract failed to load custom language though it is there

Tags: python, tesseract

> "Error: Tesseract (legacy) engine requested, but components are not
> present in /usr/local/share/tessdata/custom.traineddata"

But file is there and code works when use eng.traineddata.
Using tesseract --list-langs shows custom as loaded.
Running with --oem 3. TESSDATA_PREFIX is correct. Running with lang="eng+custom" fully ignores custom.

What can be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Message is clear: you asked tesseract to use legacy engine, but its components are not present in custom.traineddata. E.g. you can not use custom.traineddata for legacy engine.